# best way to expand path contains environment variable in C++/Linux

Tags: c++, qt, environment-variables

what's the best way to expand (or evaluate) file path contains environment variable. 
my current solution is using regex to find pattern like `${ABC}` or `$ABC`, then using `getenv` function to get the value and replace it, but I found that it's a little complex to take those exceptions into account like `\$HOME` or `'$HOME'` (in this case, the value shouldn't be considered as env variable). 
 Another requirement is that if there's some variable not defined, it would return those undefined variable names.
  so any better solution ? thanks